# ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo with Caliburn.Micro on UWP

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, caliburn.micro

I'm evaluating Caliburn.Micro for a UWP app. I'm now looking on a way to use a NavigationTransitionInfo when navigating away from a view; in particular the problem is with ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo, since I need to set the exit element referencing the gridView clicked item. Without Caliburn.Micro, I used this code:

```
private void gridView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    var info = new ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo();
    info.ExitElement = gridView.ContainerFromItem(e.ClickedItem) as UIElement;
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MyNextPage), e.ClickedItem, info);
}
```

How could I achieve the same result using Caliburn.Micro methods and INavigationService? Is there an example somewhere that shows this?

What happens if, only for this specific situation, I bypass the INavigationService and execute the Navigate method directly on the Frame?